# Calling a variable from a def function to another def function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm having a hard time with calling the recordtable variable from my def btn3function() to my def update(). Anyone can help how I can call it without any error? Here's the full detail. I hope this will help, and thank you in advance again. I'm open to any suggestion or ideas. Willing to be enlightened.

```
reg = []

def register(name, number, date, time):
    reg.append([name, number, date, time])

update()

def update(recordtable):
    for item in recordtable.get_children():
        recordtable.delete(item)

    for r in range(len(reg)):
        recordtable.insert(parent='', index='end', text='', iid=r, values=reg[r])

def btn3function(recordtable):
    top = tkinter.Toplevel(root)
    top.title("APPOINTMENTS")
    frame = tk.Frame(top)
    bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="appointments.png")
    labl = tk.Label(frame, image=bg)
    labl.img = bg
    labl.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
    frame.pack(pady=10)
    frame.pack_propagate(False)
    frame.configure(width=1000, height=790)


    name = tk.Label(frame, text="Name:", font=('Bold', 16))
    name.place(x=180, y=250)
    nameEntry = tk.Entry(frame, font=('Bold', 16))
    nameEntry.place(x=280, y=250, width=180)

    number = tk.Label(frame, text="Number:", font=('Bold', 16))
    number.place(x=180, y=300)
    numberEntry = tk.Entry(frame, font=('Bold', 16))
    numberEntry.place(x=280, y=300, width=180)

    date = tk.Label(frame, text="Date:", font=('Bold', 16))
    date.place(x=550, y=250)
    dateEntry = tk.Entry(frame, font=('Bold', 16))
    dateEntry.place(x=620, y=250, width=180)

    time = tk.Label(frame, text="Time:", font=('Bold', 16))
    time.place(x=550, y=300)
    timeEntry = tk.Entry(frame, font=('Bold', 16))
    timeEntry.place(x=620, y=300, width=180)

    register = tk.Button(frame, text="Register", font=('Bold', 16))
    register.place(x=270, y=380)

    update = tk.Button(frame, text="Update", font=('Bold', 16))
    update.place(x=400, y=380)

    delete = tk.Button(frame, text="Delete", font=('Bold', 16))
    delete.place(x=510, y=380)

    clear = tk.Button(frame, text="Clear", font=('Bold', 16))
    clear.place(x=620, y=380)

    searchNum = tk.Label(frame, text="Search Appointment by Number:", font=('Bold', 14))
    searchNum.place(x=210, y=450)
    
    searchEntry = tk.Entry(frame, font=('Bold', 14))
    searchEntry.place(x=500, y=450)

    recordlabel = tk.Label(frame, text='Select Record to Update or Delete', bg='white', font=('Bold', 14))
    recordlabel.pack(fill=tk.X)
    recordlabel.place(x=350, y=500)

    recordtable = ttk.Treeview(frame)
    recordtable.pack(fill=tk.X, pady=5, side=BOTTOM)
    recordtable['column'] = ['Name', 'Number', 'Date', 'Time']

    recordtable.column('#0', anchor=tk.W, width=0, stretch=tk.NO)

    recordtable.column('Name', anchor=tk.W, width=100)
    recordtable.column('Number', anchor=tk.W, width=100)
    recordtable.column('Date', anchor=tk.W, width=100)
    recordtable.column('Time', anchor=tk.W, width=100)

    recordtable.heading('Name', text="NAME", anchor=tk.W)
    recordtable.heading('Number', text="NUMBER", anchor=tk.W)
    recordtable.heading('Date', text="DATE", anchor=tk.W)
    recordtable.heading('Time', text="TIME", anchor=tk.W)
```

Comment: Python is statically scoped, so the free variable `recordtable` must be defined in a scope containing the *definition* of `update`, not just a *call* to update.

Comment: I'm trying to call the recordtable in the def update(): but the recordtable is inside the def btn3function(): .

Comment: See my answer below, if `recordtable` is defined within `btn3function`, pass it to `update` as a parameter

Comment: You're asking for trouble by having a `Button` named `register` as well as a function named `register` - *always* use unique names for variables.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `recordtable` variable into `update` as a parameter: `def btn3function(rt)`. I'm not sure where you're actually *calling* `update`, but when you do you should do this: `update(recordtable)` somewhere *after* the declaration of `recordtable`

Comment: That's not necessarily sufficient, because `recordtable` has to be defined somewhere that `update` can see it. We need more detail about how `register` and `update` relate to `btn3function`.

Comment: Agreed - it's not especially clear what scope `recordtable` is in here

Comment: I posted the whole code. I hope it helps

Comment: Your code doesn't show where `update` or `register` get *used*. I suspect you are assuming that if `update` is called from `btn3function` (or from a function called from `btn3function`, that it can see `recordtable`. It cannot. That requires dynamic scoping, which very few languages use. Python, like most languages, uses static scoping.

Comment: @chepner indeed...which is why I recommended OP pass `recordtable` to the function(s) that need(s) it - well said